# Dynamic div that can stretch and shrink as per content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now my search result flows out of my container and onto the footer.

Thanks for any tips.

My page structure looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="ajax_Search">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like your container has a fixed height. do not fix the height and it will grow as tall as needed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure divs expand by default. what do you mean?

Comment: On this example as you type in search box, the content div expands and shrinks to fit the results in, my results flow out for ajax_Search div and onto my footer, I am trying to make this div resizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div should expand and shrink normally, unless you have set the inner elements to float.

If the inner elements are floated, then set "overflow: auto" on the containing div.